# Getting Django forms to inherit class for custom field attributes

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms

I would like for my forms to have a `class='form-control'` attribute.

As opposed to adding:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(<form name>, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = False
        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(
                                            {'class' : 'form-control',
                                            'placeholder':self.fields[key].label
                                            })
```

to every form, it would be easier to have something like:

```
class BootstrapForm(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = False
        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(
                                            {'class' : 'form-control',
                                            'placeholder':self.fields[key].label
                                            })

class LoginForm(forms.Form, BootstrapForm):
    #.... stuff ....
```

but this doesn't work.

Is there anyway to solve this with the DRY principles?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`django-bootstrap3`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) battery.

Comment: Does replacing `class BootstrapForm(object):` with `class BootstrapForm(forms.Form):` and `class LoginForm(forms.Form, BootstrapForm):` with `class LoginForm(BootstrapForm):` work?

Comment: Yes, you can also use [django-floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It has a good example to adapt it to bootstrap3, and only makes use of templates to do so.

Comment: @alecxe That does work! Do you know why that does, and the other way doesn't? please submit an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Ben posted, thanks. I suspect mixin-approach doesn't work because of the method resolution order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying a mixin, define a base `Form` class that sets `form-control` class on every field widget:

```
class BootstrapForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = False
        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(
                                            {'class' : 'form-control',
                                            'placeholder':self.fields[key].label
                                            })
```

Then, your forms would inherit from `BootstrapForm`:

```
class LoginForm(BootstrapForm):
    # stuff
```

---

Just FYI, [`django-forms-bootstrap`](https://github.com/pinax/django-forms-bootstrap) package takes another approach - it adds `form-control` class [on the fly](https://github.com/pinax/django-forms-bootstrap/blob/master/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py#L9-L17) by introducing a custom [`|as_bootstrap`](https://github.com/pinax/django-forms-bootstrap/blob/master/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py#L20-L28) template filter:

```
<form>
    <legend>My Form</legend>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_bootstrap }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <a href="#back" class="btn">Go back</a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On the other hand, [`django-bootstrap3`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) defines [custom Field renderers](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/d62f6287be16b5c15ed6d12d1b6279f6949f3f54/bootstrap3/renderers.py) which are responsible for setting [`form-control` class](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/d62f6287be16b5c15ed6d12d1b6279f6949f3f54/bootstrap3/renderers.py#L201-L210).